# How to obtain extreme ray for unbounded problem in Cplex with Python?

Tags: python, cplex

I wanted to run the simple code of an unbounded problem in Cplex using python API:

```py
import docplex.mp.model as cpx
from docplex.util.status import JobSolveStatus

my_bdrex_SP=cpx.Model('My Benders Model Sub Problem')

# Adding variables:

v_1=my_bdrex_SP.continuous_var(name='v_1', lb=0)

v_2=my_bdrex_SP.continuous_var(name='v_2', lb=0)

# Defining the objective function 
objective_SP=0*v_1-6*v_2

# Adding constraints
my_bdrex_SP.add_constraint(4*v_1+2*v_2>=2)

my_bdrex_SP.add_constraint(-2*v_1+3*v_2>=-3)

my_bdrex_SP.add_constraint(3*v_1-1*v_2>=1)

# Solving the problem
my_bdrex_SP.minimize(objective_SP)

my_bdrex_SP.solve()

my_bdrex_SP.print_solution()

print(my_bdrex_SP.get_solve_status())
```

This problem is unbounded and Cplex gives the results as "unbounded or infeasible."

To obtain the feasibility cut, I need an extreme ray. For that, I am using the following line

```
ray = my_bdrex_SP.get_engine().get_cplex().solution.advanced.get_ray()
```

But unfortunately I am receiving an error like:

> cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexSolverError: CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.

How do I obtain the extreme ray of the unbounded problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to turn the presolve off with

```
my_bdrex_SP.parameters.preprocessing.presolve = 0
```

and you will get

```
* unbounded ray (vector): [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
* unbounded ray (expr): x+y
```